# Defining tagged types (aka branded types) in JSDoc

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript, I've [seen](https://github.com/ChromeDevTools/devtools-frontend/blob/388c37657cb8657/front_end/models/trace/types/Timing.ts) tagged types help delineate between kinds of numbers:

```
export type MilliSeconds = number&{_tag: 'MilliSeconds'};
export type MicroSeconds = number&{_tag: 'MicroSeconds'};
```

Can you do the same with [the JSDoc syntax](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, although not documented, it works just fine:

```js
/** @typedef {number&{_tag: 'MilliSeconds'}} MilliSeconds */
/** @typedef {number&{_tag: 'MicroSeconds'}} MicroSeconds */
```

You may want to create a helper to avoid inline casting:

```js
/** @param {number} value */
const toMilliSeconds = (value) => /** @type MilliSeconds */ (value);
```

Also, note that math operations will lose the type. Eg, `endMs - startMs` will only be a number. This is [true in TypeScript as well](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42218#issuecomment-1820214330), at least until operator overloading behavior is defined in both TC39 and TS.  Until then, alternatives are either more casts or helper methods like this:

```js
/**
 * @param {MilliSeconds} a
 * @param {MilliSeconds} b
 */
function subtractMilliseconds(a, b) {
  return /** @type {MilliSeconds} */ (a - b);
}
```