milliSeconds vs seconds, can JsDoc tell me when I mix things up?
I want to learn a bit TypeScript and JsDoc. A common situation for me is that I happen to mix numeric values that are not quite the same. As a simple example (not very realistic, perhaps) let us say I could mix milliseconds and seconds. In the code below I have tried to get some help from JsDoc. I edit this in Visual Studio Code and hope to see some warnings/errors, but nothing shows up.
// @ts-check

/** @typedef {number} TSseconds */
/** @typedef {number} TSmilliSeconds */

/** @type {TSmilliSeconds} */
let ms = 1;

/** @type {TSseconds} */
let sec = 2;

ms = sec;

/**
 * 
 * @param {TSseconds} secVal 
 * @returns {TSmilliSeconds}
 */
function sec2ms(secVal) {
    console.log("sec2ms", secVal);
    return 1000 * secVal;
}

/** @type {TSmilliSeconds} */
let ms2;
ms2 = sec2ms(ms);

/** @type {TSseconds} */
let sec2;
sec2 = sec2ms(ms);

I guess I have misunderstood something. How can I get some more help from JsDoc here? (Completion works.)
I have typescript installed (npm install -g typescript).
NodeJs latest stable version.

TypeScript is structurally typed - any number is assignable to any other number, even if you've given them different aliases.

@jonrsharpe Thanks, yes I have noticed. But what can I do to get the support I want/need?

You can look into "branded types". Or use an envelope, so they're actually different (type MilliSeconds = { ms: number }, for example).

@jonrsharpe It looks like "branded types" is what I need. Can I use that with JsDoc? (Oh, yes. I am a little bit lazy. I assume the answer is "yes". But just in case the answer "no" I want to know that before I try...)

@jonrsharpe I just saw there is a very nice answer to the JsDoc question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77622612/defining-tagged-types-aka-branded-types-in-jsdoc

I think the best you will be able to accomplish with Typescript is to alias the number type to better describe what the argument should be.  For example.
type Seconds = number
type MilliSeconds = number
function myTimer(arg0:Seconds, arg1:MilliSeconds){}
So when you look at the function definition there will be better clarity in what these values represent.
You could also "protect" against using seconds when you expect milliseconds by using a type helper like this.
type IsMilliSeconds<T> = T extends number
  ? `${T}` extends `${infer U}000`
    ? T
    : never
  : never;



function myTimerInMilliSeconds<T>(arg:IsMilliSeconds<T>){
return arg
}

https://tsplay.dev/WP29eN
So in this case if you have a function that expects the time in milliseconds it would error when myTimerInMilliSeconds(1)

Thanks. I do not want to use TypeScript. Though I do agree that syntax is much easier to read. (But I believe this will still not do what I want to. Just as you said, of course.)

That doesn't work either, for exactly the reason above - https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html

This is about as meaningful as naming the parameters timeinMS and timeInS. Unless you, as a programmer, actually read this, it won't do anything.

I realize you said you couldn't use TS, but I couldn't help myself and added a type that could potentially constrain an argument if you expected milliseconds but the developer passed seconds.
